# How to have a screenShot in wkwebview it has a video playing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

At first I use a wkwebView to laod a web url. This url has a video playing.
So I want to have a screenshot like this:
I had used follow API,but it does not work.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webView.scrollView.contentSize, true, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
{
    CGPoint savedContentOffset = webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect savedFrame = webView.scrollView.frame;
    webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    webView.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
    for (UIView * subView in webView.subviews) {
        [subView drawViewHierarchyInRect:subView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    }
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    webView.scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    webView.scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I got this photo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0cAn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can add WebView into the UIView as childview then you can use UIView screenshot to save the webview picture.Like

```
UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[tempView addChildView:'Your webview'];
[tempView takeSnapshot];

- (UIImage *)takeSnapshot:(UIView *)tempView {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.tempView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.tempView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    // old style [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Hi,I got this Image

Comment: it has not the video content